*.jsp endpoint on a controller
I have an application that has an endpoint that is called by other applications (APP/index.jsp) and because of this I cannot change this url.
I plan to change this jsp to a controller, but using @RequestMapping("index.jsp") doesn't trigger the controller.
Any other suffix works, but I can't change how other applications consume my application.
Is there any way I can replace this jsp file with a controller? The data returned is still the same (using thymeleaf), but I can't get a controller to work for it.
Edit 1:
The solution I'm working on is something like this other question (This one didn't work, no endpoint returns when I add this).
I saw that Spring has a class AbstractServletWebServerFactory, in which case the 'shouldRegisterJspServlet' method would return false (I tested debugging) for my scenario, but I wasn't able to set the jsp object on startup (or remove the jar containing JspServlet from classpah).
My application is a common spring boot app, no changes have been made to the controller configuration.
Edit 2:
Example application with my scenario:
https://github.com/felipeissa/jsp-demo

What? You are using .jsp path names in the @RequestMapping. LOL! Completely defeats the purpose of using it. Wrong design.

Show your controller, configuration, and ideally logging which shows what is being invoked.

This needs an effort. Not sure if it's possible to implement something like this. Some hacky way must be developed to get your requirement. It's not that simple.

Again show your configuration, controller etc. I also wonder what is according to you a common Spring Boot app? Judging from your tags you aren't using Spring Boot.

@Felipe Issa (1) Guess your goal is to change the location of URL /APP/index.jsp to be served by other classes instead of jsp. (2)web.xml, <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping><servlet-mapping><servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>, write a servlet : public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet. This is a pure example without using Spring/Spring MVC. If you use Spring/Spring MVC instead, you should also use Servlet and the corresponding URL Mapping.

Hi @M.Deinum, added an example app. No configuration was done for controller specifically.


Stop mixing Spring Boot versions (your plugin is using an older version, remove the version tag). 2. why are you both excluding tomcat and including the embedded jsp stuff that doesnb't make sense. 3. You are using @RestController where you should use @Controller. 4. You are building a war, but aren't using the SpringBootServletInitializer basically not starting your application.


There are several issues with your application as shown here.

Stop mixing Spring Boot versions (your plugin is using an older version, remove the version tag).
why are you both excluding tomcat and including the embedded jsp stuff that doesnb't make sense.
You are using @RestController where you should use @Controller.
You are building a war, but aren't using the SpringBootServletInitializer basically not starting your application.

Without 4, the other 3 won't work no matter how hard you try.
As you are apparently deploying to a Tomcat server instead of using an embedded Tomcat (due to the exclusion) you also have to make sure you are using Tomcat 10 or up else it won't work either (Spring Boot 3 requires Tomcat 10 or up).

Hey @M.Deinum, thanks for the reply. This is just a small sample from our actual app, so it does not reflect how it actually is. In any case, the point #1 is valid and I'll fix it on our app. For point 2, I add the 'embedded jsp' jar because I need it to work locally when I start the app on the IDE. Yes if I change it to only have tomcat core it works, but when I deploy the war on tomcat (or weblogic) it won't work as the jar will be present. Demo app is updated with the fix from your comments :)

Don't exclude tomcat, just mark it provided also why 2 times the plugin. Your controller doesn't return what it should return and you haven't configured view resolution either.
